# Basic Integral using integration by parts method

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate 
$$\int \frac{1-x}{1+x^2} \, dx?$$

I have been using integration by parts method $uv - \int v \, du$ but it is just like a mess. I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for integrating by parts. You can handle it if you know some substitution and a basic integral rule, look below. Same colors represent the correspondence.

**1st Hint:** $$\int \frac{1-x}{1+x^2}dx=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #B81]{\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx}-\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx}$$

**2nd Hint:** $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #B81]{\frac{d}{dx}\arctan x=\frac{1}{1+x^2}}$$

**3rd Hint:** $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{u=x^2 \Rightarrow xdx=\frac{du}{2}}$$

Comment: Nice color correspondence! (And hints too).

Comment: I became addicted to using colors in each thread :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\int \dfrac{x-1}{1+x^2}\,dx = \frac12 \int \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\,dx-\int \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$$ and it it is easier to treat each of those individually

Comment: oh my..thnk you very much guys...